# Mongodb getting error while creating new user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I just installed a fresh mongodb on Ubuntu server and when i try to adduser i am getting error

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "ADYkdfd332@@33",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)


2018-07-03T13:29:41.556+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1437:15
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 54):

This works for me:

```
db.createUser({  
 user:"test1",
 pwd:"test1",
 roles:[  
  {  
     role:"readWrite",
     db:"u8"
  }
 ],
 mechanisms:[  
  "SCRAM-SHA-1"
 ]
})
```

Answer (score 18):

**Go with following commands in Mongo Shell:**

```
use admin
db.createUser({
    user:"admin",
    pwd:"abc123",
    roles:[{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase",db:"admin"}],
    passwordDigestor:"server"
})
```

Further you can refer [enable authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

Answer (score 16):

If you use [User Management Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/) you have to set param `passwordDigestor`.

```
 db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "ADYkdfd332@@33",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ],
    passwordDigestor: "<server|client>"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

See the SCRAM-SHA-256 password creation with digest or undigest [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createUser/)

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "ADYkdfd332@@33",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ],
    passwordDigestor : "<server|client>"
  }
)
```

Comment: passwordDigestor is right option instead of digestPassword

Comment: mongo 4.0.7: Error: 'passwordDigestor' must be either 'server' or 'client', got: 'true' :

Answer (score 4):

This error comes up only when you are accessing it remotely.

If `passwordDigestor` is client then `mechanisms` is not compatible with `SCRAM-SHA-256` and only `SCRAM-SHA-1` can be used.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ],
    mechanisms: [ "SCRAM-SHA-1" ],
    passwordDigestor: "client"

  }
)
```

If `passwordDigestor` is server then both `mechanisms` i.e. `SCRAM-SHA-1` and `SCRAM-SHA-256` can be used or it works even if you don't specify it at all.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ],
    passwordDigestor: "server"

  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use "database name"

db.createUser(
   {
     user: "username",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: [ { role: "dbOwner", db: "database name" } ],
     mechanisms:[  
       "SCRAM-SHA-1"
     ]
   }
)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? Why are you "using 'database name'"?

Answer (score 0):

I am running a windows subsystem for linux using Ubuntu and was getting this error. Sometimes there's an issue that windows doesn't seem to close `mongod` correctly on `exit` so you need to `Ctrl+Shift+Esc` into task manager and close it manually.

Actually, whenever mongo seems to be doing anything unusual this seems to be the problem.

Then run `mongod`. In another terminal try adding your user again.